# Estou aprendendo python. Como usar um if com um código e depois executar outro if com outro código? é possível?

Tags: python

````
import numpy as np

print('\n\nBem vindo!!!!!\n\n')
print('------------JOGO DA LOTERIA------------\n\n')

jogo = int(input('Deseja jogar qual modalidade: \n(1) Mega-Sena\n(2) Quina\n(3) Sair\n\nDigite qual a sua opção de jogo: \n'))
    

if jogo == 1:
    print('Você está apostando na Mega-Sena!!\n')
elif jogo == 2:
    print('Você está apostando na Quina!!\n')
elif jogo == 3:
    print('Volte sempre!!\n')
else:
    print('Opção inválida')
        
sorteados_mega = sample(range(1, 61), 6)
sorteados_mega = sorted(sorteados_mega)
#print(sorteados_mega)

palpite = []

for i in range (1, 7):
    num = 0
    while num <1 or num > 60 or num in palpite:
        num = int(input(f' {i}º número - Digite um número de 1 á 60: \n'))
    palpite.append(num)
    
palpite = sorted(palpite)
print('\n\n Sua aposta é: ', palpite)


resultado = np.in1d(palpite, sorteados_mega)
acertos = len(np.intersect1d(palpite, sorteados_mega))

print('\n\nVocê ganhou na Mega-Sena!!!') if resultado.all() else print(f'\n\nVocê perdeu e acertou {acertos} numeros(s).')

print('Sorteados: ', sorteados_mega)
print('Sua aposta: ',palpite)```

    


 #Quando eu escolho a opção jogo 1, ele roda legal. quando coloco jogo 2, ele roda o jogo um, a opção 3 também...
 #a intenção é que na opção 2, eu faça rodar o jogo com os parâmetros da Quina, e a opção 3 apareça um volte sempre.
 #Se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeço.
````

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Dá uma estudada em funções e coloca cada "jogo" em uma. Assim você chama cada uma delas de acordo com o input. No modo que está montado, mesmo que você escolha outro nome de jogo, você acaba apostando sempre os mesmos 6 números da mega. Esse seria o ideal, ou então, simplesmente coloque o código da Mega Sena após o if de verificação da mega e crie um código da Quina no Else que entra na Quina.

Comment: Se quer parametrizar, então crie uma função que faz um jogo genérico (que recebe o range e a quantidade, por exemplo), e passe os parâmetros de acordo com o jogo escolhido. Algo assim: https://replit.com/@hkotsubo/Loteria#main.py

Comment: Muito obrigada, hkotsubo!!! Essa função eu não aprendi ainda, mas já vou estudar sobre isso.

Comment: Eduardo, exatamente isso. então o que estava errado, é que após o 1° If eu não coloquei comando nenhum, e pulei para o elif... Muito obrigada, pela ajuda!! Estou treinando!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Comentei ali como poderia fazer o modo mais simples e montei aqui. Veja se é isso que você imagina.

```
import numpy as np
import random

print('\n\nBem vindo!!!!!\n\n')
print('------------JOGO DA LOTERIA------------\n\n')

jogo = int(input('Deseja jogar qual modalidade: \n(1) Mega-Sena\n(2) Quina\n(3) Sair\n\nDigite qual a sua opção de jogo: \n'))
    

if jogo == 1:
    print('Você está apostando na Mega-Sena!!\n')
        
    sorteados_mega = random.sample(range(1, 61), 6)
    sorteados_mega = sorted(sorteados_mega)
    print(sorteados_mega)

    palpite = []

    for i in range (1, 7):
        num = 0
        while num <1 or num > 60 or num in palpite:
            num = int(input(f' {i}º número - Digite um número de 1 á 60: \n'))
        palpite.append(num)
        
    palpite = sorted(palpite)
    print('\n\n Sua aposta é: ', palpite)


    resultado = np.in1d(palpite, sorteados_mega)
    acertos = len(np.intersect1d(palpite, sorteados_mega))

    print('\n\nVocê ganhou na Mega-Sena!!!') if resultado.all() else print(f'\n\nVocê perdeu e acertou {acertos} numeros(s).')

    print('Sorteados: ', sorteados_mega)
    print('Sua aposta: ',palpite)
    
    
elif jogo == 2:
    print('Você está apostando na Quina!!\n')
    
    
    sorteados_quina = random.sample(range(1, 81), 5)
    sorteados_quina = sorted(sorteados_quina)
    print(sorteados_quina)

    palpite = []

    for i in range (1, 6):
        num = 0
        while num <1 or num > 80 or num in palpite:
            num = int(input(f' {i}º número - Digite um número de 1 á 80: \n'))
        palpite.append(num)
        
    palpite = sorted(palpite)
    print('\n\n Sua aposta é: ', palpite)


    resultado = np.in1d(palpite, sorteados_quina)
    acertos = len(np.intersect1d(palpite, sorteados_quina))

    print('\n\nVocê ganhou na Quina!!!') if resultado.all() else print(f'\n\nVocê perdeu e acertou {acertos} numeros(s).')

    print('Sorteados: ', sorteados_quina)
    print('Sua aposta: ',palpite)
    
        
elif jogo == 3:
    print('Volte sempre!!\n')
else:
    print('Opção inválida')
```